# Serilog Dynamically enrich a context

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

Is there any possibility to dynamically override or extend the log template in Serilog?

I have a parser class which parses XML line by line and I want to extend the log entry with the line number. I have already written an enricher that does that, but I have to globally override the default logger at the start of the function and reset it at the end, which is difficult to even look at (from a programming perspective) :D

What are the other options with Serilog or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I finally found a solution that fit my needs.

I used the `LogContext.PushProperty` mechanism to push the `XmlReader` (or rather a wrapper object, because the type-matching with the destructuring is exact and `XmlReader` is a factory which returns many different classes) into the `LogContext` and added a custom destructuring to `LoggerConfiguration` to detect objects of that wrapper type and then format it to my liking.